# is the current Adobe Flash 'ransomware vulnerability' affecting Ubuntu users?

Tags: updates, security, flash, vulnerability

Currently there is an important release from Adobe telling users to update their Flash after learning of certain vulnerabilities where users computer are infected with [ransomware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ransomware). One of the many news articles about the issue can be seen [HERE](http://www.cbc.ca/news/technology/adobe-flash-emergency-update-1.3526340).

My question is, how does this affect Ubuntu users using Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox, and other web browsers that use Adobe Flash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu is affected the same way as the other vulnerable OSs: Windows, Macintosh, Linux, and Chrome OS.

> Successful exploitation could cause a crash and potentially allow an 
>   attacker to take control of the affected system.

In other words, Ubuntu is as exploitable as the the rest of the systems running the vulnerable Flash plugin. Flash for Linux has been updated to version 11.2.202.616, and is available through the repositories.

[info source](https://helpx.adobe.com/security/products/flash-player/apsb16-10.html)

Comment: if I am using Chrome Version 49.0.2623.110 (64-bit) am I still vulnerable? the link you provided states the updated version of Adobe Flash Player for Google Chrome is 21.0.0.213. How do I check which version of Flash Player is installed in Chrome?

Comment: I don't use Chrome, but a quick search came upon this: https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/enabling-flash-player-chrome.html